# Motherboard for ML/kubernetes/gaming

Tags: motherboard

I have a PC with a [Gigabyte X299 board](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/X299-AORUS-Gaming-7-Pro-rev-10#kf), but the BIOS support for virtualization is just absolute junk. I tried flashing an upgrade of the BIOS to a 3.0 version so I could work with [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) and it will only boot in recovery mode.

I'm contemplating upgrading the MB, but I find it very hard to obtain good information on support for both multiple GPU's (for ML) and virtualization (other work) at the same time. Searching both keywords at the same time suddenly gets you into graphics card virtualization which is not what I want at all.

Can folks recommend a Multi-GPU mainboard (supporting 2 more more NVIDIA GPUs, preferably with support for 4, w/ SLI) also known to have good virtualization support in the BIOS/UEFI settings?

I also use it to run games occasionally, so good gaming support is a plus, but that's a secondary requirement.

The CPU I have is an AMD 1950X Threadripper and I'd like to reuse as well as the EKWB cooling, NVMe drives and ATX case.

I expect the RAM might need to be updated to the newer spec suitable for the MB, and I want to expand anyway and believe in matched sets... capacity for at least 128 GB would be desirable.

Will dual boot Ubuntu and Windows, so Linux friendly is key too.

I don't have a specific budget, but would spend if I thought I was getting something forward compatible. Exploratory stages right now.

Also having the sinking feeling that I might regret not moving up to the TR4X socket. But trying not to go there, as I'm only rarely able to max all 32 threads, since I tend to hit memory issues first (48 GB currently).